# Call CMake from python script results in "Could not create named generator"

Tags: python, cmake

I'm building a project that should be able to move freely between machines. In order to not have hundreds of MB of libs I'm writing a series of python scripts that download and build the dependencies as well as my own project. I'm using CMake to generate VS projects.

To call CMake I build a command line and I use python `subprocess.check_call` as below

```
cmakeCmd = ["cmake.exe", '-G "Visual Studio 11 Win64"', build_path]
retCode = subprocess.check_call(cmakeCmd, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT, shell=True)
```

The problem is that if I use `-G` option from CMake I get the following error regardless of the generator I choose:

```
CMake Error: Could not create named generator  "Visual Studio 11 Win64"
```

I was thinking that should be some enviroment variable missing but the python path is complete with all my systems' variables.

What is odd is that if I don't set the generator and let CMake choose the default one the script runs fine. I have no ideia why.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You need to split the `-G` flag from its value in the command.  Python appears to be effectively invoking

```
cmake "-G Visual Studio 11 Win64" <build_path>
```

What you want is more like:

```
cmakeCmd = ["cmake.exe", "-G", "Visual Studio 11 Win64", build_path]
```

Comment: The problem was that I was using the double quotes in the generator's name since this is the way I do in the command line. Python already wraps the arguments with quotes. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Should be:

```
cmakeCmd = ['cmake', '-G', 'Visual Studio 11 Win64', build_path]
```

For the sake of *cross-platformness*, I recommend to do the following:

```
if sys.platform.startswith('win'):
    shell = True
else:
    shell = False

retCode = subprocess.check_call(cmakeCmd, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT, shell=shell)
```

if you plan to work with the project on several platforms (including Unix OS family). By the way, since you are using `shell=True` on Windows, you can omit `.exe` suffix in the `cmakeCmd` (which is good if this script is used on Unix OS family too as there is no such thing as `.exe`).

Comment: Why shell should be disabled in Unix?

Comment: Because then it will simply not work. `:)` It is not related to CMake in particular, but to invocation of any external commands from Python in general.

Comment: I made a quick test on a linux machine and what I see is that using shell with the command being a list will not work. If the list has one element with the entire command line it works fine. God why!